# three.js bind Plane to proxy Object transformations

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to transform a Plane according to a Object3D (position and rotation). That Plane is used as a clippingPlane.

If I call Plane.applyMatrix4( Object.matrixWorld ) it just applies the matrix once, and doesn't bind the Plane to that matrix for future transformations.
However if I call the same function in a loop the transformations applied to the Plane are continuous.
EG if I call Object.rotate.z = 1 once, and then Plane.applyMatrix4( Object.matrixWorld ) in a loop, the Plane rotates 1 unit along the Z axis at every loop.

Any ideas?

Being this Plane used as a clipping plane, I also tried to transform it in the shader material of the mesh being clipped, and it maybe would be the best performance-wise, but I'm not so skilled to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

I would just to this:

```
object.add( plane );
```

In this way, `plane` is a child of `object`. All transformations applied to `object` are also applied to `plane`. Besides, it's now very easy to transform `plane` relative to `object`.

Comment: It won't work, because Plane is not an instance of Object3D, so can't be a child of an Object3D.
Plane is in THREE.Math, it's just an object containing a normal vector and a constant = distance from point 0.
I'm going to study the "clipping advanced" example, that looks going in the direction I need.

Comment: Oh sry, it was not clear to me that you are using `THREE.Plane`. The mentioned example might be a good starting point.

Comment: No prob mate. I think I found a quick way using some THREE.Matrix4 methods. I'll post a feature request asap, because binding clipping planes to objects is quite necessary in the real world scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest solution I found is to reset and apply Object's .matrixWorld to the Plane. As I said before, it would be great to add useful transformation and "binding" methods to the THREE.Plane object, since it's used as clipping plane too.

Right now I did this way:

```
// will store the object's inverse transformations matrix in world coords
var inversePrevMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

function loop(){

    // reset plane previous transformations
    plane.applyMatrix4( inversePrevMatrix );

    // apply actual object matrix in world coordinates 
    plane.applyMatrix4( object.matrixWorld );

    // set prevMatrix
    inversePrevMatrix.getInverse( object.matrixWorld );
}
```